# when replacing the (MAX(s.salary) - MIN(s.salary) by its aliase it will not work .. why?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT dm.emp_no, 
       e.first_name, 
       e.last_name,
       MAX(s.salary) - MIN(s.salary) AS salary_difference,
       CASE WHEN MAX(s.salary) - MIN(s.salary) > 30000 
            THEN 'Salary was raised by more then $30,000'
            ELSE 'Salary was NOT raised by more then $30,000'
        END AS salary_raise
    FROM dept_manager dm
    JOIN employees e ON e.emp_no = dm.emp_no
    JOIN salaries s ON s.emp_no = dm.emp_no
    GROUP BY s.emp_no;
```

when replacing the (MAX(s.salary) - MIN(s.salary) by its aliase it will not work .. why ?

Comment: The alias is not available at that point in the queries execution

Comment: You should provide the full error message, becuase "it will not work" is not enough. The full error message is something like: `"ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'salary_difference' in 'field list'"`, which simply means that MySQL does not know where column `salary_difference` is.  The WHY can only be answered by the people who created this piece of software.

Comment: @ErgestBasha: Is was not saying there is a way, did I ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should read [Problems with Column
> Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)
>
> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
> different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
> clauses to refer to the column.

In your case alias would work if an outer query is involved, which by the way would be excess.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  emp_no,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        salary_difference,
        CASE WHEN salary_difference > 30000 
             THEN 'Salary was raised by more then $30,000'
             ELSE 'Salary was NOT raised by more then $30,000'
         END AS salary_raise
FROM (
      SELECT dm.emp_no, 
             e.first_name, 
             e.last_name,
             MAX(s.salary) - MIN(s.salary) AS salary_difference
       FROM dept_manager dm
       JOIN employees e ON e.emp_no = dm.emp_no
       JOIN salaries s ON s.emp_no = dm.emp_no
       GROUP BY s.emp_no
      ) as tbl
```